# DB Error: no such field (Joomla - view contact)

Tags: contacts, joomla

please I need help. When I go into the backend to see the details of a contact, I get the following error:

```
Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
DB Error: no such field

Return to home page.
```

I cant find any error logs, nothing is displayed on the debug, I just dont know where to else look for an issue.

- I also upgraded to the latest version 4.7.14
- I ran the database upgrade successfully
- I downloaded a sql file of the entire database
  and compared it with a fresh new installation - no difference on the
  structure

Please, what else can I check?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could check two further things:
- the ACL settings for your login (i.e your usergroup);
- the assets table, most use the (paid) component ACL manager for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!
I had a broken custom profile with broken custom fields.
I was not even able to delte those fields and that profile from the backend.
Had to go into the Database and delete the entire table which is related to that profile.

That fixed the problem.